# How can I achieve better standard error values in Stata?

Tags: stata

I am struggeling to find the specific commands to achieve lower standard errors within simple regressions.

I would be thankful for your help.

Comment: `regress` does pooled OLS, and your `xtreg Y X1 X2 X3` with no options does the "random effects FGLS" panel regression. If you want GLS, you need to provide with a covariance structure, which is done by your `xtset firmID Time`. OLS requires nothing. To figure out what is really done under the hood, the "Methods and formulas" section of the Stata pdf manual would help.

Comment: The edit impoverishes the question considerably. What was the motivation?

Answer (score 1):

Pooled regression on a panel-data sample, **indeed**, *does not take the time dimension into account*. This is why it is called "pooled": we ignore the fact that for each cross-section we have a time series, and we treat the whole panel-data sample as though it were a cross-sectional one, as if, say,  $x_{it}$ and $x_{i,t+1}$ are diffrenet cross sections.